# What is A * A here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am unable to understand what does A * B and A * A means. Here is the question.

Let * be a new operator on sets is defined as follows: Given two sets A and B, A * B = (A ∩ B)'.

i. Draw a Venn Diagram for A * B

ii. By using the laws of the algebra of sets show that the following is true:

• (A * A) * (B * B) = A ∪ B

• (A * B) * (A * B) = A ∩ B

Do I proceed with assuming A*B is just A * B = (A ∩ B)'

What about A * A? Is it just AA ∩ BB = A ∪ B?

Thank you in advance. This seemed a bit confusing.

Comment: $A*A$ should have nothing to do with $B$

Comment: $A*B$ is defined to be $(A\cap B)'$.  This gives you the form of the operator $*$ applied to two inputs.  If you want to do $A*A$, then you take the formula above and replace $B$ with $A$ everywhere it appears.

Comment: A∗A by your definition is $(A \cap A)'.$

Comment: For simplifying things, it helps to remember that $A=A\cap A = A\cup A$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are to use the definition of the operation that you have been given.  Applying it, $A*A=(A\cap A)'$  You should be able to simplify that.  Now apply the definition to the two problems-rewrite the left side in terms of the set connectives you know and work though to the right side.